# How to show that $f(x)=x^p$ does not have Macluarin series if $p$ is not an integer?

Tags: taylor-expansion

It is because $x^p$ is not differentiable at $0$.

So we have to say that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ does not exists. Precisely we have to show that left limit does not exists.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{p-1}$$
How to show that left limit does not exists? How its affecting the result when $p$ is an integer.

Comment: The problem is that it is not differentiable infinitely many times at 0 (consider the first derivative such that the power is negative) - the limit exists for p >= 1

Answer (score 1):

Differentiability is only defined on interior points of the domain. For a non-integer $p$ we can not define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) := x^p$ on $\mathbb{R}$. What for example does $f(-1)$ mean if $p = \frac{1}{2}$? The square root of negative numbers is not defined (and no, $\sqrt{-1}$ is not $i$ - even if it were, we could not define $f$ as a function that maps into the reals).

Therefore we can only define $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But $0$ is not in the interior of $[0, \infty)$ and therefore we can not talk about derivatives.

Comment: Is this answer right? Isn't $p = \frac{4}{3}$ a counter example to the proof of this answer?

Comment: How is $(-1)^\frac{4}{3}$ a real number?

Comment: If this has come from any sort of real analysis, it will take the real valued root as the principal root for $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ would it not?

Comment: I see... One *can* define it that way, but you can not do that for any $x$.

Comment: But you can for some x (any fraction with odd denominator) so your answer would need to deal with that case. As it stands it is incomplete.